# How to insert new element in the xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, transformation

I am new to XSLT working on XML to XML transformation. I want to add a element in the xml depending on the condition.

I have this employee information and requirement is to add the  tag inside the  element for each and every employee.

```
**Scenario1**
<Employee>
 <Name>Check1</Name>
 <Position>
  <org>
   <orgName>COMPANY</orgName>
   <orgType>ABC</orgTyp>
  <org>
 </Position>
</Employee>

**Scenario2**
<Employee>
 <Name>Nitesh</Name>
 <Position>
  <role>Consultant</role>
 </Position>
</Employee>

**Scenario3**
<Employee>
 <Name>Nitesh</Name>
</Employee>
```

I wrote the below code but it is not giving me desired output.

`

```
<xsl:when test="not(xs:Position)">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- And everything inside it -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
        <!-- Add node -->
        <xs:Position>
            <xs:Organization>
                <xs:Organization_Type>1<xsl:value-of select="$OrgType"/>
                </xs:Organization_Type>
                <xs:Organization_Code>2<xsl:value-of select="$OrgCode"/>
                </xs:Organization_Code>
                <xs:Organization_Name>3<xsl:value-of select="$OrgName"/>
                </xs:Organization_Name>
            </xs:Organization>
        </xs:Position>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="xs:Position">
    <xsl:variable name="element" select="xs:Position"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(xs:Position/xs:Organization/xs:Organization_Type='COMPANY')">
            <xs:Organization>
                <xs:Organization_Type>1<xsl:value-of select="$OrgType"/>
                </xs:Organization_Type>
                <xs:Organization_Code>2<xsl:value-of select="$OrgCode"/>
                </xs:Organization_Code>
                <xs:Organization_Name>3<xsl:value-of select="$OrgName"/>
                </xs:Organization_Name>
            </xs:Organization>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$element"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:when>`
```

Comment: What is the expected result in each scenario?

Comment: Output like scenario 1

Comment: "*Output like scenario 1*" Really? So you do not want to output the `<role>Consultant</role>` node in scenario #2?

Comment: Apologies  if my reply was unclear and I want to output as  org tag inside position tag and if in position tag any other value is already present then in output I need to add org tag and other tag should remain untouched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand your attempted code - esp. since major parts of it are missing.

I *think* you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="default-org">
    <org>
        <orgName>default name</orgName>
        <orgType>default type</orgType>
    </org>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Employee[not(Position)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <Position>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$default-org"/>
        </Position>     
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Position[not(org)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$default-org"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<root>
   <Employee>
      <Name>A</Name>
      <Position>
         <org>
            <orgName>COMPANY</orgName>
            <orgType>ABC</orgType>
         </org>
      </Position>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Name>B</Name>
      <Position>
         <role>Consultant</role>
      </Position>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Name>C</Name>
   </Employee>
</root>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Employee>
      <Name>A</Name>
      <Position>
         <org>
            <orgName>COMPANY</orgName>
            <orgType>ABC</orgType>
         </org>
      </Position>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Name>B</Name>
      <Position>
         <role>Consultant</role>
         <org>
            <orgName>default name</orgName>
            <orgType>default type</orgType>
         </org>
      </Position>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <Name>C</Name>
      <Position>
         <org>
            <orgName>default name</orgName>
            <orgType>default type</orgType>
         </org>
      </Position>
   </Employee>
</root>
```